# CSS and JS can't load in Windows Server and using domain

Tags: css, laravel, iis

I park my laravel website in windows server. if i run `php artisan serve`, the web run perfectly. But when i try to use domain, all css and js can't load. I check the status in console, network all is 200, but when i open the link `https://example.com/subfolder/asset/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js` , it show empty page, no error.

i already

- give full permission to IUSRS
- restart the server
- change httaccess/webconfig

but still not working. if i run in local using php artisan serve, everything ok. but when i use localhost and domain, the css and js can't load

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        Options +Indexes 
    # or #
    IndexIgnore *
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" env=HTTPS
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
    Header unset X-Powered-By
</IfModule>

# Blocks some XSS attacks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\|%3E) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
    RewriteRule .* index.php [F,L]
</IfModule>

# Protect Against  Injection
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(HEAD|TRACE|DELETE|TRACK) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.\.\/ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} boot\.ini [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tag\= [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ftp\:  [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} http\:  [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} https\:  [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|%3D) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(\[|\]|\(|\)|<|>|ê|"|;|\?|\*|=$).* [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(%24&x).* [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(%0|%A|%B|%C|%D|%E|%F|127\.0).* [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(globals|encode|localhost|loopback).* [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(request|select|insert|union|declare).* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*WordPress_logged_in_.*$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Expect-CT enforce,max-age=2592000,report-uri="https://foo.example/report"
</IfModule>

    
# Security Headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    # Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
    Header set X-Frame-Options Deny
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
   
    Header set Referrer-Policy "same-origin"
    
</IfModule>
```

webconfig

```
 <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.php" />
                <add value="default.aspx" />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="index.html" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: if you are using IIS then .htaccess is not relevant at all because that is only read by Apache. Also make sure you set your website document root to your `public` directory and all your JS and CSS files are under that directory (you may need to use a bundler like laravel-mix or vite). The path `asset/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js` looks very wrong when serving the website via a webserver

Comment: all js and css already under public. it works when i used php artisan serve and use ip http://192.1.x.x , but can'load if using localhost or domain. in console all the file path status is 200, but when open its blank page.

Comment: So you have a file under `public/subfolder/asset/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js` in your project?

Comment: inetpub/wwwroot/subfolder/public/asset/js

i just check the log in inetpub/wwwroot/log

2023-03-21 06:21:21 ip GET /subfolder- 443

Comment: So in order to set it up to work in the same way as it did with `php artisan serve` you need to create a new IIS website configuration with root directory being `inetpub/wwwroot/subfolder/public`. You also need to specify the hostname that IIS will listen on to serve that page specifically and then set up the DNS entry for that hostname. For example if you want your website to be at `https://example.com` you need to setup a DNS entry that resolves `example.com` to your IP. The easiest way to do this (for local development only) is adding a line in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: Once you've done this you can access `https://example.com/asset/js/bootstrap.min.js`